# Facebook's og:image doesn't work correctly now?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

A couple of days ago wrong images started to appear in Facebook posts during posting, although pages being posted have correct og:image tag, pointing to large enough images.

Does anyone know what a problem would it be? Maybe somehow related to recent API upgrades?

Examples:

1) http://bigpicture.ru/?p=633696 -- OG Object Debugger shows "og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough" warning. The page has:

```html
<meta property="og:image" 
content="http://bigpicture.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Jpsportcars19-800x440.jpg"/>
```

which is large enough, obviously.

2) http://postila.ru/post/26862259 -- the debugger gives the same warning. Again, the page has correct og:image tag, the picture is large enough. During manual posting we see that Facebook takes wrong picture, one of small pictures present on the page.

Any ideas what is going on with Facebook today and how to fix it?

Comment: I've got the exact same issue recently too, will update you if I fix mine. I think it's a Facebook change.

Comment: thank you JordanC26. I'd appreciate if you share any update on this issue.

Comment: The issue seems known to Facebook and many others, found some bug reports: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1565027973760906/